# routerLink on button elements doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I have a dashboard which is contain some information from firebase
and i have a button Like this (more) [image]

and when i click on it, it doesn't work or redirect me to my specific page 
this my code in html file

```html
<table class="table table-inverse">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">First Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Email </th>
        <th scope="col">Country</th>
        <th scope="col">City</th>
        
        <th scope="col">Salary</th>
        <th scope="col">ID</th>
        <th scope="col">Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody >
      <tr *ngFor="let item of employees">
        
        <th >{{item.firstName}}</th>
        <th >{{item.lastName}}</th>
        <th >{{item.email}}</th>
        <th >{{item.country}}</th>
        <th >{{item.city}}</th>
        
        <th >{{item.salary}}</th>
        <th >{{item.key}}</th> 
        <th> <a href="" [routerLink]="['/employee/employee/]" class="btn btn-primary">more <i class="fa fa-info-circle" ></i>
        </a></th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>   
  </table>
```

i have import this in the app.module.ts

```
import { RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
```

And also i added this in the route config

```
{path:'employee/:id',component:EmployeeInfoComponent},
```

Comment: Perhaps, `[routerLink]="['/employee/', item.key/]"`?

Comment: im not enable to click to the button to redirect me, even i change the path

Comment: Your route config path is `'employee/:id'`, but your routerLink is this `'/employee/employee/` (a single quote is missing). These need to work together, with a matching route pattern. Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Something that may help you: https://angular.io/guide/router#link-parameters-array

Comment: when i go to the path 'employee/employee' its work but when i click to the button in the table it doesn't work!
when i remove the ngFor it will be enable to redirect me

Comment: isnt it supposed to be like this [routerLink]="['/employee/', item]"

Comment: Can you show us screenshot of developers tool console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[routerLink]="['/employee/employee/]`"  your routerLink not match with your routes it should be like `{path:'employee/:id',component:EmployeeInfoComponent},` . And you missed close single quotes.
Try to this `[routerLink]="['/employee/, item.key]”`

Comment: you also missed single closing quote in [routerLink]="['/employee/, item.key]”